# Find Top N Most Frequent Sequence of Numbers in List of a Billion Sequences

Tags: algorithm

Let's say I have the following list of lists:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],  # sequence 1
     [6, 5, 10, 11],  # sequence 2
     [9, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5],  # sequence 3
     [12, 12, 6, 5],  # sequence 4
     [5, 8, 3, 4, 2],  # sequence 5
     [1, 5],  # sequence 6
     [2, 8, 8, 3, 5, 9, 1, 4, 12, 5, 6],  # sequence 7
     [7, 1, 7, 3, 4, 1, 2],  # sequence 8
     [9, 4, 12, 12, 6, 5, 1],  # sequence 9
]
```

Essentially, for any list that contains the target number `5` (i.e., `target=5`) anywhere within the list, what are the top `N=2` most frequently observed subsequences with length `M=4`?

So, the conditions are:

1. if `target` doesn't exist in the list then we ignore that list completely
2. if the list length is less than `M` then we ignore the list completely
3. if the list is exactly length `M` but `target` is not in the `Mth` position then we ignore it (but we count it if `target` is in the `Mth` position)
4. if the list length, `L`, is longer than `M` and `target` is in the `i=M` position`(or`i=M+1`position, or`i=M+2`position, ...,`i=L`position) then we count the subsequence of length`M`where`target` is in the final position in the subsequence

So, using our list-of-lists example, we'd count the following subsequences:

```
subseqs = [[2, 3, 4, 5],  # taken from sequence 1
           [2, 3, 4, 5],  # taken from sequence 3
           [12, 12, 6, 5],  # taken from sequence 4
           [8, 8, 3, 5],  # taken from sequence 7
           [1, 4, 12, 5],  # taken from sequence 7
           [12, 12, 6, 5],  # taken from sequence 9
]
```

Of course, what we want are the top `N=2` subsequences by frequency. So, `[2, 3, 4, 5]` and `[12, 12, 6, 5]` are the top two most frequent sequences by count. If `N=3` then all of the subsequences (`subseqs`) would be returned since there is a tie for third.

**Important**

This is super simplified but, in reality, my actual list-of-sequences

1. consists of a few billion lists of positive integers (between 1 and 10,000)
2. each list can be as short as 1 element or as long as 500 elements
3. `N` and `M` can be as small as 1 or as big as 100

My questions are:

1. Is there an efficient data structure that would allow for fast queries assuming that `N` and `M` will always be less than 100?
2. Are there known algorithms for performing this kind of analysis for various combinations of `N` and `M`? I've looked at suffix trees but I'd have to roll my own custom version to even get close to what I need.
3. For the same dataset, I need to repeatedly query the dataset for various values or different combinations of `target`, `N`, and `M` (where `target <= 10,000`, `N <= 100` and `M <= 100). How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: I think you're in the wrong StackExchange site.

Comment: This is a reasonable data science question to a real world problem

Comment: I think after reversing and concatenating your lists with a stop symbol in between you could use a custom [suffix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array). When your target number comes in you basically build an [LCP-Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array) for all suffixes starting with your target number (taking the stop symbols into account). If you expect multiple queries of the same target number and different M's then you could also precombute the LCP-Array.

Comment: How do you count two or more targets that meet the criteria?

Comment: @Neil I don’t understand your question. The user would specify the target, N, and M.

Comment: Is it possible that a given list contains the target several times?

Comment: How would one count the entry _eg_, `target=5`, `M=2`, `{{5,3,5,2,5,5},...}`? As a short-circuit `{3,5}` or all `{3,5}, {2,5}, {5,5}` or something else? It makes the difference what homomorphisms one can apply. Are these sequences or sets?

Comment: @Neil It would be "all". This is precisely what is happening in sequence 7. However, it also depends on what `N` is in terms of whether or not the sequence makes the cut since what we are interested in is the `N` most frequent subsequences with `target` and length `M`

Comment: @Damien Yes, a given list may contain the target several times. See sequence 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending on my comment. Here is a sketch how you could approach this using an out-of-the-box suffix array:

1) reverse and concatenate your lists with a stop symbol (I used 0 here).

```
[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 11, 10, 5, 6, 0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 8, 9, 0, 5, 6, 12, 12, 0, 2, 4, 3, 8, 5, 0, 5, 1, 0, 6, 5, 12, 4, 1, 9, 5, 3, 8, 8, 2, 0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 7, 1, 7, 0, 1, 5, 6, 12, 12, 4, 9]
```

2) Build a [suffix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array)

```
[53, 45, 24, 30, 12, 19, 33, 7, 32, 6, 47, 54, 51, 38, 44, 5, 46, 25, 16, 4, 15, 49, 27, 41, 37, 3, 14, 48, 26, 59, 29, 31, 40, 2, 13, 10, 20, 55, 35, 11, 1, 34, 21, 56, 52, 50, 0, 43, 28, 42, 17, 18, 39, 60, 9, 8, 23, 36, 58, 22, 57]
```

3) Build the [LCP array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array). The LCP array will tell you how many numbers a suffix has in common with its neighbour in the suffix array. However, you need to stop counting when you encounter a stop symbol

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0]
```

4) When a query comes in (target = 5, M= 4) you search for the first occurence of your target in the suffix array and scan the corresponding LCP-array until the starting number of suffixes changes. Below is the part of the LCP array that corresponds to all suffixes starting with 5.

```
[..., 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 0, ...]
```

This tells you that there are two sequences of length 4 that occur two times. Brushing over some details using the indexes you can find the sequences and revert them back to get your final results.

**Complexity**

- Building up the suffix array is O(n) where n is the total number of elements in all lists and O(n) space
- Building the LCP array is also O(n) in both time and space
- Searching a target number in the suffix is O(log n) in average
- The cost of scanning through the relevant subsequences is linear in the number of times the target occurs. Which should be 1/10000 on average according to your given parameters.

The first two steps happen offline. Querying is technically O(n) (due to step 4) but with a small constant (0.0001).

Comment: I'm working in Python. So, you think I'll have to roll my own custom suffix array implementation? Additionally, why do we need to reverse and concatenate the sequences?

Comment: The suffix array can be standard, but you might want to adopt the LCP array. Since you want to find all subsequences with length M that end with the target number but  suffix arrays can only help you finding subsequences that start with the target number you have to revert the sequences. You can also build a suffix array for each sequence but concatenating will be more efficient.

Comment: Is space and time complexity going to be an issue if I have a billion lists that are between 10 and 100 in length?

Comment: Since my input are already integers and not alphabets, how does lexicographical sorting play a role here? Right now, the lists are generated by taking unique "states" and assigning them the next available integer value. For better performance, should I be concerned with how I am assigning those integer values? Right now, the first state that I encounter in the data is automatically assigned to integer value `1` and the second observed state is assigned to `2` and so on. However, these states may be very rare. Perhaps, the states should be assigned by how often they are observed?

Comment: Suffix arrays work for both sequence of characters and sequence of numbers, just by replacing lexicographical order through normal sorting. So nothing special here. I don't think clever assignment of states to id's makes a difference here.

Comment: I'm working my way through this but I'm failing to see how I can obtain the top-K most frequent sequences that are of length `M` and with a specific `target`. If I understand correctly, the LCP only tells me the length of the subsequence match with it's closest neighbor but there is no count/frequency info. What I need is a frequency count of how often each subsequence (with the same length `M` and some specified `target`) is observed. Then, I need to return those, say, top 10 most frequently observed subsequences that have the same length `M` and with some specified `target`

Comment: Your understanding of the LCP is correct. Now when scanning through the relevant part (step 4) and look for continuous sub-sequences (of the LCP) where the LCP entries are larger than M. The length of these sequences + 1 tells you the number of times that the associated sequence (of the original data) of length M appears in the original data.

Comment: @slaw did you end up actually implementing it in python? would you mind sharing your code?